# Outlook 2016 Rules upgrade

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

I am running outlook 2016, when I open the rules options, there is an "Upgrade Now" button, with the text.

> We recommend that you upgrade your rules for better performance, unless you also use Outlook 2002 or earlier

[image]

As far as I know my rules are working fine as they are.  I googled around and did not find anything about what this upgrade might do.

What is this upgrade and what does it do?

What will work less well, and what new features will it bring?

Answer (score 0):

This option will available if you have previous Outlook rule.  You are able to convert your previous Outlook rules via click "Upgrade Now".

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?  While I appreciate your taking time to answer, I am not sure what you are trying to say.  I don't have any previous rules and there is an option above for importing the old rules if I had them.